# Proceso largo y pesado en php

Tags: php

verán tengo un sistema que genera muchos pdf (unos 20,000 - 30,000)y aproximadamente tarda unas 2 o 3 horas generando, serán aproximadamente 2 o 3 por segundo, la cosa es que cuando otro usuario trata de entrar al sistema, si alguien esta generando los pdf, simplemente se queda intentando entrar al sistema y solo lo logra cuando el usuario de los pdf termina, pausa o cierra el proceso largo.
¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia? ya que veo que php no soporta programación multi hilo.

Comment: mmm.. pero de eso se deberia encargar el servidor web, no php. Php solo construye las paginas y las devuelve... debe estar pasando otra cosa aca...

Comment: ¿Generar 20,000 o 30,000 pdf? ¿Seguro que se está implementando la lógica adecuada? Ni siquiera la Biblioteca Nacional creo que haría eso.

Comment: en realidad es una imagen

Answer (score 0):

puedes provar no dandole la carga al servidor http: `apache/ngnix` si no directamente al mismo servidor ejemplo:

```
//si quieres enviar algun parametro extra seria:
//$parametros = "nombre=parametro1&apellido=parametro2" etc..
shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/crearpdf.sh '.$parametros);
```

creadpdf.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup php -f "/var/www/html/crearpdf.php?$1" >> /var/www/html/crearpdf.log &
exit;
```

> Esto enviara la ejecucion del script a segundo plato y no sobrecargara el servidor http apache/ngnix

y con ajax ya puedes ir viendo crear pdf log dando un [flush](http://php.net/manual/es/function.flush.php) por cada pdf creado
algo como el numero del pdf echo $i."\n"; 
leees el documento cada x time y envias las ultimas lineas ejemplo:
estado del la ejecucion se an creado 250 pdf restan x cantidad!